# Debugging python2 under windows

Tags: debugging, python

For a while I've been trying now to get python debugging under windows to work with a precompiled GVim to work (with dynamical python2/python3 support):

```
MS-Windows 32 Bit GUI Version mit OLE-Unterstützung
Übersetzt von mool@tororo
Riesige Version mit GUI. Ein- (+) oder ausschließlich (-) der Eigenschaften:
...
+autochdir          +clipboard          +dialog_con_gui     -farsi              +job                +lua/dyn            +num64              +python/dyn         +spell              +terminal           +vertsplit          +writebackup        
+autoservername     +cmdline_compl      +diff               +file_in_path       +jumplist           +menu               +ole                +python3/dyn        +startuptime        -termresponse       +virtualedit        -xfontset
...
```

Until now, I've tried [vdebug](https://github.com/vim-vdebug/vdebug) and vimspector
[vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector).

But I have not managed to get one of this working (under windows) when trying to debug a python27 project (I need to use a dedicated python 2.7 interpreter, which is part of the project, not the builtin one, and not an installed with a windows installer, but rather checked out/copied from a repository). Does anybody know if it's possible to do debugging with the given requirements (precompiled vim, windows, python27 Interpreter from the project which is not installed using an installer)?

Answer (score 1):

If using vimspector, you can set the `python` launch argument to point to the python interpreter that `debugpy` uses to debug your application.

It's even in the example https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector#python